# Ruby on Rails namespace routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, routes

I'm currently trying to fix the routes for my order resource. I have an 'admin' namespace which holds key resource actions for administering the various resources within my application.

I want a guest to be able to create an order outside the admin namespace, whereas I want the all the order resource's actions to be available within the admin namespace. However, when I specify the ':create' action outside the namespace, the ':index' action is not available within the namespace. My only theory is both these action share the same path, i.e. /orders, because when I remove the ':create' action from outside the namespace, the ':index' action starts working inside the namespace.

So with that in mind, how can I access the ':create' action outside the namespace and the ':index' action inside the admin namespace for the order resource?

Here is my route setup:

```
  resources :orders, :only => [:new, :create, :update_country]

  scope '/admin' do
      resources :orders
  end
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I noticed when running 'rake routes' that the order#create was utilising the 'orders_path/orders_url':

```
orders POST   /orders(.:format)                     orders#create
```

This meant the orders#index within the admin namespace had no path to reference within the view:

```
       GET    /admin/orders(.:format)               orders#index
```

Therefore the solution would be to use different syntax to achieve a namespace with bespoke path values, e.g. 'admin_orders_path' as seen below:

Routes.rb

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :orders
  end
```

Result of rake routes:

```
              orders POST   /orders(.:format)                     orders#create
        admin_orders GET    /admin/orders(.:format)               admin/orders#index
```

In hindsight this seems like a more clear and concise way of managing my admin namespace within the application; having defined admin path/url values for a routes resource.

Answer (score 1):

The method 'new' is used for rendering a resource's create form while the method 'create' is called upon submission of this form. So, for enabling an order to be created outside the admin namespace and the rest of the actions within the namespace, give this a try:

```
resources :orders, only: [:new]

scope '/admin' do
    resources :orders, except: [:new]
end
```